# select and update using one command in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, sql-update

I want to use this code to update answers then select from answers and subscribers but the code seems not working....Please help.

```
{

$sub_ip = ($_POST["secret"]);
$secret_code = htmlentities($_POST["secret"]);

$check = $db->prepare("UPDATE subscribers SET sub_ip = :sub_ip WHERE sub_code = ':secret_code' =  (SELECT * from answers,subscribers where answers.secret_code LIKE '%:secret_code%' AND subscribers.sub_code = ':secret_code'");

$check->execute(array(":secret_code" => $secret_code));
if($check->rowCount() > 0 )
  {
    while($getans = $check->fetch())

    {
```

Comment: ???  WHERE sub_code = '$secret_code' =  ( 
    SELECT * ...... to many assignment and to mani column selected  in subquery .. (at least) .. and don't use php var in sql you are at risk for sqlinjection

Comment: You are using PHP. To append value of a PHP variable to a string, you can type `"sub_ip = " +$sub_ip`! Please take a look about writing SQL statements!